# WebSocket server on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, websocket

Is there any library to run a WebSocket server on Windows Phone 8? Or samples?

There is the SuperWebSocket library (http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com) but it does not support the .NET for Windows Phone 8.

Comment: You want to run websocket server or client in windows8 phone?

Comment: @shivakumar Server...

Comment: What exactly you want to do by having websocket server on mobile? Do you want to allow others also to open websocket connection to your phone?

Comment: Yes. I want to host a web page on the phone. This page will open a WebSocket connection back to the phone, to stream data... Normal HTTP requests are not enough (too slow).

Comment: anybody figure this out ??